# Error configuración en Moodle

Tags: moodle

El problema que tengo es le siguiente me da este error en moodle

> Fatal error: $CFG->dataroot is not configured properly, directory does not exist or is not accessible! Exiting.

El archivo `config` , lo revise y esta bien , he estado migrando el moodle de un hosting a otro en el hosting anterior funcionaba ok y en este esta igual con su respectiva BD y datos corrrectos y me sigue dando este error .

**¿Qué puede estar mal ?** 
Pregunta , puede que el usuario no tenga permisos para acceder a la carpeta dataroot ?

Comment: puedes agregar tu archivo config?

Answer (score 0):

En la url de `wwwroot` debes siempre incluir el `http`

```
$CFG->wwwroot = 'http://tudominio.com/moodle';
```

Tambien, la carpeta de configuración siempre debe estar fuera de la carpeta `www`

```
$CFG->dirroot = '/home/tudominio/public_html/moodle';
$CFG->dataroot = '/home/tudominio/moodle_data';
```

Y obviamente darle permisos 777 a la carpeta moodle_data.

Answer (score -1):

Si le quieres dar permisos a una carpeta específica en Ubuntu server corre el siguiente comando:

```
chmod -R 777 ./nombre_carpeta
```

Comment: No está claro que sea problema de permisos. ¿Qué pasa si necesita `sudo` para cambiar los permisos?